# Change mail subject with Elao\ErrorNotifierBundle

Tags: php, email, symfony, production

Everything in the title! Just want to know if it's possible or not to change the mail subject, I'm working with Symfony2.6 and the [Elao\ErrorNotifierBundle](https://github.com/Elao/ErrorNotifierBundle) to send error mails in the prod environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt look like there's an option to change the e-mail subject.
However you can manually change the subject to your liking, in the Notifier class.

https://github.com/Elao/ErrorNotifierBundle/blob/master/Listener/Notifier.php#L306

Comment: Do I need to extend this class so ?

Comment: That's one way to do it, yes. You can read more about overriding parts of a bundle here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html

An easier way would be to open op the bundle, and just edit the code, but pretty sure thats bad practice :-)

Comment: That's what I found when you say me to change the class, yes. It works pretty well. A bad practice and useless, because when I will update this bundle : game over :D. Thanks!